# How to limit the SQL Server Developer edition to the Standard edition?

Tags: sql-server, licensing

I need to limit my Dev environment to the Standard Edition features.

I have installed SQL Server Standard Edition on my Prod server. I have license for SQL Server Developer Edition. There is a way to install the Standard edition by using my Dev license and use it according to the license agreement?

Comment: You can vote for such feature 
[here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/e1761f1e-2797-ed11-a81b-000d3adb7ffd)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an MSDN subscription, you can download install the MSDN version of SQL Server SE for development and testing using the MSDN product keys. Otherwise, you could still use DE for dev and testing but the onus will be on you to make sure you don't use Enterprise Edition only features. The sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features DMV will show any used.

Comment: I wonder whether this answer is still valid in 2022